# Fit a wide table in two colums

Tags: tables

I'm trying to fit this table in my paper. The paper is in two columns, so I guess the table needs to take the whole page (which is fine). I tried to make font smaller and to use {table*}, but it still doesn't fit the page or overlaps the rest of the text.

This is my table:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{F1-Values}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Naive Bayes}                      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{K-NN}                             & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Decision Tree}                    \\
\textbf{String Representation}         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BoW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TF-IDF} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BoW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TF-IDF} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BoW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TF-IDF} \\
                                       & with       & without    & with        & without      & with       & without    & with        & without      & with       & without    & with        & without      \\
\textbf{Removal of Punctuation}        & 0,9750     & 0,9835     & 0,9373      & 0,9562       & 0,8723     & 0,8802     & 0,9543      & 0,9651       & 0,9641     & 0,9601     & 0,9394      & 0,9501       \\
\textbf{Removal of Stopwords}          & 0,9824     & 0,9835     & 0,9671      & 0,9562       & 0,8692     & 0,8802     & 0,8681      & 0,9651       & 0,9579     & 0,9641     & 0,9603      & 0,9501       \\
\textbf{Removal of Numbers}            & 0,9764     & 0,9835     & 0,9659      & 0,9671       & 0,8812     & 0,8802     & 0,9521      & 0,9651       & 0,9694     & 0,9641     & 0,9602      & 0,9603       \\
\textbf{Stemming}                      & 0,9787     & 0,9835     & 0,9541      & 0,9671       & 0,8640     & 0,8812     & 0,9312      & 0,9651       & 0,9576     & 0,9694     & 0,9508      & 0,9603      
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I'm kinda desperate and in a rush, so any help is welcome.

Comment: never use `[]` on table, but for a two column span use `\begin{table*}` the * form spans both columns

Comment: Please provide some crucial pieces of information about your document. E.g., which document class you do you employ? Which page size do you employ: A4, US Letter, something else? How wide is the text block (if it's not the document class's default width)? Which font and which font size do you use?

Answer (score 1):

- With my first answer version I was to to late, @Mico bit me for few ten seconds with the almost the same solution ... :-(
- So I rewrite it with use of the `tabularray` package and for fonts use `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font which are a bit narrower from default cm fonts, that it a bit differ from it.
- Package `tabularray` offer clear and concise syntax for writing of table, which enable to separate the table design from its contents.
- If this suggestion is suitable to you, is hard to say since you not provide important information as are used  document class, page layout, fonts ...
- If this proposition is not acceptable, you should to consider to rotate table to landscape orientation.
- MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \small
\begin{tblr}{colsep = 3pt,
            colspec = {@{} Q[l, font=\bfseries]
                     *{12}{X[c]} 
                       @{}},
            cell{1}{2,6,10} = {c=4}{},
            cell{2}{even}   = {c=2}{},
           }
    \toprule
F1-Values   &   Naive Bayes 
                &   &   &   &   K-NN    
                                &   &   &   &   Decision Tree   
                                                &   &   &   \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-9}
    \cmidrule[l]{10-13}
\SetCell[r=2]{} String Representation        
            &   BoW   
                &   &   TF-IDF
                        &   &   BoW
                                &   &   TF-IDF
                                        &   &   BoW
                                                &   &   TF-IDF
                                                        &   \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-3}  \cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-7}  \cmidrule[lr]{8-9}
    \cmidrule[lr]{10-11}   \cmidrule[l]{12-13}
     & with  & w/o   & with  & w/o 
            & with  & w/o   & with  & w/o
                            & with  & w/o   & with  & w/o   \\
    \midrule
Removal of Punctuation
    & 0,9750    & 0,9835    & 0,9373    & 0,9562    & 0,8723    & 0,8802     
    & 0,9543    & 0,9651    & 0,9641    & 0,9601    & 0,9394    & 0,9501    \\
Removal of Stopwords
    & 0,9824    & 0,9835    & 0,9671    & 0,9562    & 0,8692    & 0,8802     
    & 0,8681    & 0,9651    & 0,9579    & 0,9641    & 0,9603    & 0,9501    \\
Removal of Numbers
    & 0,9764    & 0,9835    & 0,9659    & 0,9671    & 0,8812    & 0,8802     
    & 0,9521    & 0,9651    & 0,9694    & 0,9641    & 0,9602    & 0,9603    \\
Stemming                      
    & 0,9787    & 0,9835    & 0,9541    & 0,9671    & 0,8640    & 0,8812     
    & 0,9312    & 0,9651    & 0,9576    & 0,9694    & 0,9508    & 0,9603    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 0):

If you apply some abbrevations in the header cells and if you are willing to forego **bold-facing** the material in the left-hand column, it'll still be necessary to execute `\small` (for a 10% linear reduction in font size) in order to get the table to fit inside the text block. As the second table in the following screenshot demonstrates, employing the machinery of the `siunitx` package to round all numbers in all 12 data columns to 3 decimal digits would allow you to stick with the default font size, aka `\normalsize`.

Two questions: What information are readers supposed to get from being shown the fourth digit after the decimal marker for all numbers? And, how sure are you that your readers will actually pick up the information you intend them to get when you show them four decimal digits for all numbers?

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type, enable rounding of numbers

\begin{document}

\begin{table*} % use a 'table*' environment, which spans both columns

%%% first version: no rounding to three digits
\begingroup % localize scope of next two instructions
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX determine intercolumn whitespace

\caption{Keep all 4 digits, switch to \texttt{\string\small}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{12}{c} }
\toprule
F1-Values 
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Naive Bayes}                      
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{K-NN}                             
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Decision Tree} \\
  \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} \cmidrule{10-13} 
String Representation
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BoW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TF-IDF} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BoW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TF-IDF} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BoW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TF-IDF} \\
  \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} 
  \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} 
  \cmidrule{10-11} \cmidrule{12-13} 
  & with & w/o & with & w/o & with & w/o & with & w/o & with & w/o & with & w/o \\
\midrule
Remove Punctuation & 0,9750 & 0,9835 & 0,9373 & 0,9562 & 0,8723 & 0,8802 & 0,9543 & 0,9651 & 0,9641 & 0,9601 & 0,9394 & 0,9501 \\
Remove Stopwords   & 0,9824 & 0,9835 & 0,9671 & 0,9562 & 0,8692 & 0,8802 & 0,8681 & 0,9651 & 0,9579 & 0,9641 & 0,9603 & 0,9501 \\
Remove Numbers     & 0,9764 & 0,9835 & 0,9659 & 0,9671 & 0,8812 & 0,8802 & 0,9521 & 0,9651 & 0,9694 & 0,9641 & 0,9602 & 0,9603 \\
Stemming           & 0,9787 & 0,9835 & 0,9541 & 0,9671 & 0,8640 & 0,8812 & 0,9312 & 0,9651 & 0,9576 & 0,9694 & 0,9508 & 0,9603 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\endgroup

\bigskip
%%% second version: round to 3 decimal digits
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX determine intercolumn whitespace

\caption{Round to 3 digits, keep default font size}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
    l 
    *{12}{S[table-format=1.3, output-decimal-marker={,},
            round-mode=places, round-precision=3] }}
\toprule
F1-Values 
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Naive Bayes}                      
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{K-NN}                             
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Decision Tree} \\
  \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} \cmidrule{10-13} 
String Representation
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BoW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TF-IDF} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BoW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TF-IDF} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BoW} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TF-IDF} \\
  \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} 
  \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} 
  \cmidrule{10-11} \cmidrule{12-13} 
  & {with} & {w/o} & {with} & {w/o} & {with} & {w/o} & {with} & {w/o} & {with} & {w/o} & {with} & {w/o} \\
\midrule
Remove Punctuation & 0,9750 & 0,9835 & 0,9373 & 0,9562 & 0,8723 & 0,8802 & 0,9543 & 0,9651 & 0,9641 & 0,9601 & 0,9394 & 0,9501 \\
Remove Stopwords   & 0,9824 & 0,9835 & 0,9671 & 0,9562 & 0,8692 & 0,8802 & 0,8681 & 0,9651 & 0,9579 & 0,9641 & 0,9603 & 0,9501 \\
Remove Numbers     & 0,9764 & 0,9835 & 0,9659 & 0,9671 & 0,8812 & 0,8802 & 0,9521 & 0,9651 & 0,9694 & 0,9641 & 0,9602 & 0,9603 \\
Stemming           & 0,9787 & 0,9835 & 0,9541 & 0,9671 & 0,8640 & 0,8812 & 0,9312 & 0,9651 & 0,9576 & 0,9694 & 0,9508 & 0,9603 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: huh, you bit me for few seconds ... now need to rewrite my proposition :-)

Comment: @Zarko - So sorry... :-)

Comment: Don't worry, I rewrote my original soluti0n so that now use `tabularray` package and different fonts ...